# How to build an array of objects in C++, that all inherit from a main class?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object, inheritance

I am new to C++, and would like some help.

I need to create an array of objects, and from what I understood, it is done using :

```
MyObject* instance = new MyObject[nb_of_instances_in_array];
```

Though, it doesn't quite fit my needs.

I have a main object from which inherits 3 other objects of varying methods and attributes.

mainObject <- Object1

mainObject <- Object2 <- Object3

Now I want to create an array that can contain Object1s, Object2s, and Object3s. I tried doing something like :

```
int nb_of_obj, i;
cin >> nb_of_obj;
mainObject* arrayOfMainObjects = new mainObject[nb_of_obj];
for(i = 0;i<nb_of_obj;i++)
{
//Menu to select Object to append to the array
 arrayOfMainObjects[i] = Object2(args...);\\there are between 3 and 5 args for each object
}
delete arrayOfMainObjects;
```

and I also tried a more C-oriented method using stdlib.h's malloc and free.

```
using namespace std;

size_t max_size();
     return (size_t)(max(max(sizeof(Object1),sizeof(Object2)), max(sizeof(Object3), sizeof(mainObject))));

mainObject* arrayOfMainObjects = NULL;
arrayOfMainObjects = (mainObject*) malloc(nb_of_obj*max_size());
//Globally, same code than above
free(arrayOfMainObjects);
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I even tried accessing the next "spot" in the array doing something like :

```
*(arrayOfMainObjects + i*max_size()) = Object2(args...);
```

instead of :

```
arrayOfMainObjects[i] = Object2(args...);
```

Comment: You don't actually tell us what is wrong with what you tried (and generally don't use `malloc` in C++ except for special needs).

Comment: I'd suggest using a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<mainObject>>`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ If he is going for a low overhead (Only reason really to use arrays in this situation) then using 'std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Object >  >' is going to slow it down marginally.  (Both for creation and deletion)

Answer (score 1):

Let's inspect why the following line doesn't work for you.

`mainObject* arrayOfMainObjects = new mainObject[nb_of_obj];`

Each element in arrayOfMainObject has the size `sizeof(mainObject)`.

Objects that inherit from mainObject will be larger than mainObject if the inherited object contains some extra data.
For example  `sizeof(Object2)>=sizeof(mainObject) // always true!`.

So when you try to construct inherited Objects in the array, there is only space for `sizeof(mainObject)` and the rest get's sliced off.

To fix this, your array can consist of pointers to mainObject and you can cast the pointers to the type of the inherited object.

But now, to avoid memory leak, each pointer in the array has to be freed when no longer used.

You can use smart pointers and be free of the problem. Something like

`std::unique_ptr<mainObject>* arrayOfMainObjects = new std::unique_ptr<mainObject>[nb_of_obj];`

EDIT: Don't forget that `delete arrayOfMainObjects` is still needed.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly what you're saying, the following code should work :

    using namespace std;

    size_t max_size();
         return (size_t)(max(max(sizeof(Object1),sizeof(Object2)), max(sizeof(Object3), sizeof(mainObject))));

    mainObject* arrayOfMainObjects = NULL;
    arrayOfMainObjects = (mainObject*) malloc(nb_of_obj*max_size());
    //Globally, same code than above
    free(arrayOfMainObjects);

But it does not. The program crashes if I try to append more than 1 object to the array.

Comment: @Dogeek I think that might work, but I could be entirely wrong. Can you post the code where the crash happens?

Answer (score -1):

Just keep it simple:

```
class MyObject: public mainObject
{
}

MyObject* instance = new MyObject[nb_of_instances_in_array];
```

And everything will be easier.